# How do I group multiple nested XML in SQL with FOR XML PATH depending on the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

I have a query that formats my results in an XML. Although it is the format that I need it to be, it's not grouping the necessary columns I need it to be grouped by.

```sql
SELECT (SELECT BatchNumber,
               TotalCount,
               CAST(TotalAmount AS decimal(18,2)) AS TotalAmount,
               TotalRetainage
        FOR XML PATH('Summary'), TYPE) ,
       (SELECT (    SELECT 'Success' AS ProcessStatus,
                           '' AS ProcessMessage,
                           BatchNumber AS BatchNumber,
                           '' AS TransactionNumber,
                           '' AS VoidedDate
                    FOR XML PATH('Response'), TYPE),
               AddressNumber,
               Amount,
               BusinessUnit,
               Company,
               DateGL,
               DateInvoice,
               DocumentType,
               DocumentNumber,
               GLOffset,
               LineNumber,
               NameRemark,
               PayStatusCode,
               PaymentHandlingCode,
               SupplierInvoiceNumber,
              (SELECT DetailAccountModeGL AS AccountModeGL,
                       DetailAccountNumberInput AS AccountNumberInput,
                       DetailAmount AS Amount,
                       DetailLedgerTypes LedgerTypes,
                       DetailLineNumber AS LineNumber,
                       DetailNameAlphaExplanation AS NameAlphaExplanation,
                       DetailNameRemarkExplanation AS NameRemarkExplanation,
                       DetailObjectAccount AS ObjectAccount,
                       DetailSubledgerGL AS SubledgerGL,
                       DetailSubledgerType AS SubledgerType, 
                       DetailSubsidiary AS Subsidiary
                FOR XML PATH('Details'), TYPE)
        FOR XML PATH('Invoice'), TYPE, ROOT('Invoices'))
FROM #ExpenseConsolidated 
FOR XML PATH('InvoiceIntegrationBatch')
```

This is the result I'm getting back

```xml
<InvoiceIntegrationBatch>
  <Summary>
    <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
    <TotalCount>2</TotalCount>
    <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
    <TotalRetainage>0</TotalRetainage>
  </Summary>
  <Invoices>
    <Invoice>
      <Response>
        <ProcessStatus>Success</ProcessStatus>
        <ProcessMessage />
        <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
        <TransactionNumber />
        <VoidedDate />
      </Response>
      <AddressNumber>0.000000000000000e+000</AddressNumber>
      <Amount>2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
      <BusinessUnit>        4362</BusinessUnit>
      <Company>04362</Company>
      <DateGL>116173</DateGL>
      <DateInvoice>116173</DateInvoice>
      <DocumentType>JG</DocumentType>
      <DocumentNumber>1.599032800000000e+007</DocumentNumber>
      <GLOffset>    </GLOffset>
      <LineNumber>0.000000000000000e+000</LineNumber>
      <NameRemark>                              </NameRemark>
      <PayStatusCode> </PayStatusCode>
      <PaymentHandlingCode>   </PaymentHandlingCode>
      <SupplierInvoiceNumber>                         </SupplierInvoiceNumber>
      <Details>
        <AccountModeGL>2</AccountModeGL>
        <AccountNumberInput>        4362.10410.582       </AccountNumberInput>
        <Amount>2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
        <LedgerTypes>AA</LedgerTypes>
        <LineNumber>1.000000000000000e+000</LineNumber>
        <NameAlphaExplanation>TEST Alpha Explanation</NameAlphaExplanation>
        <NameRemarkExplanation>Test Name Remark Explanation</NameRemarkExplanation>
        <ObjectAccount>10410 </ObjectAccount>
        <SubledgerGL>2016    </SubledgerGL>
        <SubledgerType>X</SubledgerType>
        <Subsidiary>582     </Subsidiary>
      </Details>
    </Invoice>
  </Invoices>
</InvoiceIntegrationBatch>
<InvoiceIntegrationBatch>
  <Summary>
    <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
    <TotalCount>2</TotalCount>
    <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
    <TotalRetainage>0</TotalRetainage>
  </Summary>
  <Invoices>
    <Invoice>
      <Response>
        <ProcessStatus>Success</ProcessStatus>
        <ProcessMessage />
        <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
        <TransactionNumber />
        <VoidedDate />
      </Response>
      <AddressNumber>0.000000000000000e+000</AddressNumber>
      <Amount>-2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
      <BusinessUnit>        4362</BusinessUnit>
      <Company>04362</Company>
      <DateGL>116173</DateGL>
      <DateInvoice>116173</DateInvoice>
      <DocumentType>JG</DocumentType>
      <DocumentNumber>1.599032800000000e+007</DocumentNumber>
      <GLOffset>    </GLOffset>
      <LineNumber>0.000000000000000e+000</LineNumber>
      <NameRemark>                              </NameRemark>
      <PayStatusCode> </PayStatusCode>
      <PaymentHandlingCode>   </PaymentHandlingCode>
      <SupplierInvoiceNumber>                         </SupplierInvoiceNumber>
      <Details>
        <AccountModeGL>2</AccountModeGL>
        <AccountNumberInput>        4362.10410.580       </AccountNumberInput>
        <Amount>-2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
        <LedgerTypes>AA</LedgerTypes>
        <LineNumber>2.000000000000000e+000</LineNumber>
        <NameAlphaExplanation>Test Alpha Explanation 2</NameAlphaExplanation>
        <NameRemarkExplanation>Test Name Remark Explanation 2</NameRemarkExplanation>
        <ObjectAccount>10410 </ObjectAccount>
        <SubledgerGL>2016    </SubledgerGL>
        <SubledgerType>X</SubledgerType>
        <Subsidiary>580     </Subsidiary>
      </Details>
    </Invoice>
  </Invoices>
</InvoiceIntegrationBatch>
```

But what I actually need is the Invoices Grouped together cause all of this is under one batch like the XML below:

```xml
<InvoiceIntegrationBatch>
  <Summary>
    <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
    <TotalCount>2</TotalCount>
    <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
    <TotalRetainage>0</TotalRetainage>
  </Summary>
  <Invoices>
    <Invoice>
      <Response>
        <ProcessStatus>Success</ProcessStatus>
        <ProcessMessage />
        <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
        <TransactionNumber />
        <VoidedDate />
      </Response>
      <AddressNumber>0.000000000000000e+000</AddressNumber>
      <Amount>2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
      <BusinessUnit>        4362</BusinessUnit>
      <Company>04362</Company>
      <DateGL>116173</DateGL>
      <DateInvoice>116173</DateInvoice>
      <DocumentType>JG</DocumentType>
      <DocumentNumber>1.599032800000000e+007</DocumentNumber>
      <GLOffset>    </GLOffset>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <NameRemark>                              </NameRemark>
      <PayStatusCode> </PayStatusCode>
      <PaymentHandlingCode>   </PaymentHandlingCode>
      <SupplierInvoiceNumber>                         </SupplierInvoiceNumber>
      <Details>
        <AccountModeGL>2</AccountModeGL>
        <AccountNumberInput>        4362.10410.582       </AccountNumberInput>
        <Amount>2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
        <LedgerTypes>AA</LedgerTypes>
        <LineNumber>1.000000000000000e+000</LineNumber>
        <NameAlphaExplanation>TEST Alpha Explanation</NameAlphaExplanation>
        <NameRemarkExplanation>Test Name Remark Explanation</NameRemarkExplanation>
        <ObjectAccount>10410 </ObjectAccount>
        <SubledgerGL>2016    </SubledgerGL>
        <SubledgerType>X</SubledgerType>
        <Subsidiary>582     </Subsidiary>
      </Details>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <Response>
            <ProcessStatus>Success</ProcessStatus>
            <ProcessMessage />
            <BatchNumber>6.777209000000000e+006</BatchNumber>
            <TransactionNumber />
            <VoidedDate />
        </Response>
        <AddressNumber>0.000000000000000e+000</AddressNumber>
        <Amount>-2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
        <BusinessUnit>        4362</BusinessUnit>
        <Company>04362</Company>
        <DateGL>116173</DateGL>
        <DateInvoice>116173</DateInvoice>
        <DocumentType>JG</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>1.599032800000000e+007</DocumentNumber>
        <GLOffset>    </GLOffset>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <NameRemark>                              </NameRemark>
        <PayStatusCode> </PayStatusCode>
        <PaymentHandlingCode>   </PaymentHandlingCode>
        <SupplierInvoiceNumber>                         </SupplierInvoiceNumber>
        <Details>
            <AccountModeGL>2</AccountModeGL>
            <AccountNumberInput>        4362.10410.580       </AccountNumberInput>
            <Amount>-2.390000000000000e+005</Amount>
            <LedgerTypes>AA</LedgerTypes>
            <LineNumber>2.000000000000000e+000</LineNumber>
            <NameAlphaExplanation>Test Alpha Explanation 2</NameAlphaExplanation>
            <NameRemarkExplanation>Test Name Remark Explanation 2</NameRemarkExplanation>
            <ObjectAccount>10410 </ObjectAccount>
            <SubledgerGL>2016    </SubledgerGL>
            <SubledgerType>X</SubledgerType>
            <Subsidiary>580     </Subsidiary>
        </Details>
    </Invoice>
  </Invoices>
</InvoiceIntegrationBatch>
```

Please note that I am aware that the datatypes are messed up at the moment. But I've been banging my head with how to group these together properly.

Below are test data creates and inserts

```sql
CREATE TABLE #ExpenseConsolidated (
TotalCount int,
TotalAmount decimal(18,2),
TotalRetainage decimal(18,2),
BatchNumber varchar(200),
AddressNumber varchar(200),
Amount decimal(18,2),
BusinessUnit varchar(200),
Company varchar(200),
DateGL varchar(200),
DateInvoice varchar(200),
DocumentType varchar(200),
DocumentNumber varchar(200),
GLOffset varchar(200),
LineNumber varchar(200),
NameRemark varchar(200),
PayStatusCode varchar(200),
PaymentHandlingCode varchar(200),
SupplierInvoiceNumber varchar(200),
DetailAccountModeGL varchar(200),
DetailAccountNumberInput varchar(200),
DetailAmount decimal(18,2),
DetailLedgerTypes varchar(200),
DetailLineNumber varchar(200),
DetailNameAlphaExplanation varchar(200),
DetailNameRemarkExplanation varchar(200),
DetailObjectAccount varchar(200),
DetailSubledgerGL varchar(200),
DetailSubledgerType varchar(200),
DetailSubsidiary varchar(200),
DetailReverseVoid varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO #ExpenseConsolidated 
SELECT 2,0,0,'6777209', '0', 239000, '        4362', '04362', '116173', '116173', 'JG', '15990328', '    ', '0', '', '', '', '', '2', '        4362.10410.582       ', 239000, 'AA', '1', 'Reclass Consultant Fee Sample1', 'Sample1', '10410 ', '2016    ', 'X', '582     ' , ' '
UNION
SELECT 2,0,0,'6777209', '0', -239000, '        4362', '04362', '116173', '116173', 'JG', '15990328', '    ', '0', '', '', '', '', '2', '        4362.10410.580       ', -239000, 'AA', '2', 'Reclass Consultant Fee Sample2', 'Sample2', '10410 ', '2016    ', 'X', '580     ' , ' '
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible sample.
At least, DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE plus INSERT statements.

Comment: Hi @YitzhakKhabinsky - I added the DDL Create and Inserts. Hope you can help me out with this one!

Comment: I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
(SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 20), '-', ''), ' ', ''), ':','') AS BatchNumber,
           TotalCount,
           TotalAmount,
           TotalRetainage
FROM #ExpenseConsolidated  FOR XML PATH ('Summary'), ELEMENTS, TYPE),
(SELECT (   SELECT 'Success' AS ProcessStatus,
                           '' AS ProcessMessage,
                           BatchNumber AS BatchNumber,
                           '' AS TransactionNumber,
                           '' AS VoidedDate
                    FOR XML PATH('Response'), TYPE),
               AddressNumber,
               Amount,
               BusinessUnit,
               Company,
               DateGL,
               DateInvoice,
               DocumentType,
               DocumentNumber,
               GLOffset,
               LineNumber,
               NameRemark,
               PayStatusCode,
               PaymentHandlingCode,
               SupplierInvoiceNumber,
              (SELECT DetailAccountModeGL AS AccountModeGL,
                       DetailAccountNumberInput AS AccountNumberInput,
                       DetailAmount AS Amount,
                       DetailLedgerTypes LedgerTypes,
                       DetailLineNumber AS LineNumber,
                       DetailNameAlphaExplanation AS NameAlphaExplanation,
                       DetailNameRemarkExplanation AS NameRemarkExplanation,
                       DetailObjectAccount AS ObjectAccount,
                       DetailSubledgerGL AS SubledgerGL,
                       DetailSubledgerType AS SubledgerType, 
                       DetailSubsidiary AS Subsidiary
                FOR XML PATH('Details'), TYPE)
        FROM #ExpenseConsolidated 
        FOR XML PATH('Invoice'), ROOT('Invoices'), ELEMENTS, TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('InvoiceIntegrationBatch')
```

I apologize for the horribly formatted question. But this link below is what saved me

[Combine XML from T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408359/combine-xml-from-t-sql)

I basically just split out the totals by doing a top 1, then just combined Invoices